# How does autocorrelated noise models converge to white noise models when considering kinematic tracking models?

Tags: statistics, correlation, kinematics, kalman-filter, noise

In the article: A jerk model for tracking highly maneuvering targets
see
http://eprints.iisc.ac.in/2710/

The jerk model is explained.
What happens with the process noise matrix Q if the limit is taken ($\alpha\rightarrow\infty, \sigma^2\rightarrow\infty$). The author suggests that the model reduces to a constant white noise jerk model.
It does not seem to work, does anyone know if these limits can be taken?
If we define $q = \frac{2 * \sigma_j^2 }{ \alpha}$, then take the limit of $\alpha$ and $\sigma^2$ to infinity, then entry q_23 inside the noise matrix Q should converge to zero but instead it converges to $\frac{q}{2}$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just  heads up that it's going to be difficult for a lot of people to access that paper ? Maybe there's a free link somewhere ?

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the link and it is now Open Source.

Comment: I'm glad that I helped. Unfortunately it looks too complex and not possible for me to invest the required time ( and even then, understanding is no certainty ) but hopefully it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the paper, it does seem that $q_{23}$ should go to zero as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$. From the paper

$$
q_{23} = \frac{1 + \alpha^2 T^2 - 2 \alpha T + 2 \alpha T e^{-\alpha T} + e^{-2 \alpha T} - 2 e^{-\alpha T}}{2\alpha^4}
$$

The $e^{-\alpha}$ terms will go to zero as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$, and the $\alpha^4$ in the denominator will grow faster than the $\alpha^2$ in the numerator.

Am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. If you take the limit of $\alpha \rightarrow\infty$ then your comment is valid and the author also gives a Q with this limit. However, the author also suggests (and Bar Shalom as well) that the model should converge to a constant white noise jerk model for high Q. This means to my understanding that both $\sigma,\alpha\rightarrow\infty$  where q is defined as a finite quotient as described above. In other words, the noise matrix Q should converge to the Q corresponding to that of the WN jerk model and not all zeros. I hope this helps.